# How can I disable a jest mock for a particular test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I have created a working Mock for Axios:

```js
// __mocks__/axios.js
// Based on https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

const axios = jest.createMockFromModule("axios");
const log = console.log.bind(console);

axios.create = () => {
  log(`Running axios.create`);
  return {
    get: () => {
      log(`Running get`);
      return {
        status: 500,
        statusText: "Internal Server Error",
        body: {
          onFire: "Mock API response from mock axios module",
        },
      };
    },
  };
};

module.exports = axios;
```

This works fine in my tests - the mock is loaded automatically and the 'throws an error' test works:

```js
describe(`getLatestPrice`, () => {
  it(`throws an error when the response is bad`, async () => {
    expect(() => {
      log(`Should throw`);
      return getLatestPrice(assetCode);
    }).toThrow();
  });

  it(`gets a single price by stream code`, async () => {
    // Disabling the mock isn't working
    jest.unmock("axios");
    const price = await getLatestPrice(assetCode);
    log(`price`, price);
    expect(price).toEqual({
      ...
    });
  });
})
```

However the second test - which calls `jest.unmock()` - still uses the mocked library.

**How can I disable mocking for a single test?**

Update: reading https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2649 I've also tried using `requireActual()` to override the mock:

```js
const actualAxios = jest.requireActual("axios");
const mockAxios = require("axios");
mockAxios.create = actualAxios.create;
```

But calls to `axios.create()` still invole the mock.

Comment: Note to self: reading https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules "To opt out of this behavior you will need to explicitly call jest.unmock('moduleName') in tests that should use the actual module implementation." - unmock() doesn't seem to unmock a module like I thought but rather changes the mock that will be used.

Comment: Looks like this may not be possible: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2649

Comment: Actually, the link in @mikemaccana's comment has the answer, use jest.requireActual('moduleName')

Comment: My context for wanting to turn off a mock was a manual mock of a node_module dependency. Using jest.unmock('module-name') worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with mocking useSelector, which I wanted to behave normally in other tests. The only thing that eventually worked was to mock mocked useSelector with the actual useSelector. So first make sure to have way to access the actual module:

```
import {useSelector as actualUseSelector} from "react-redux"
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
```

then I've done my mocking

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
  useSelector: jest.fn()
}));
```

inside tests that needed modified redux state added

```
useSelector.mockImplementation(callback => {
  return callback({
    sliceA: {...initialStateSliceA},
    sliceB: {...initialStateSliceB},
    sliceC: {...initialStateSliceC, importantData: [{d: 1}, {d: 2}]}
  })
})
```

and then in tests where I needed original useSelector

```
useSelector.mockImplementation(()=>actualUseSelector)
```

and it worked!

**UPDATE**

Actually the above solution doesn't work as intended, it worked in one case, but for wrong reasons. It was still a mock function (and if you think about it, it makes sense). But eventually I found a working solution:

you have to recreate the whole redux anew:

```
const actualRedux = jest.requireActual('react-redux')
```

and only then mock useSelector or useDispatch with the actual ones:

```
useSelector.mockImplementation(actualRedux.useSelector)
useDispatch.mockImplementation(actualRedux.useDispatch)
```

Comment: Nice and very readable code!

Answer (score 0):

The style of mocking you perform is global mocking. All tests that use the "axios" instances in essence are hard wired to return a 500 response. To achieve per test behavior you will need to mock "axios" locally in the test. Then you can fix your mock in each test to respond in a way you expect it to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).